# Alamofire response for base64 string

Tags: ios, iphone, alamofire, nsurlsession, alamofireimage

I am using Alamofire for networking request. It works fine except one issue.

```
manager!.request(mutableURLRequest).responseJSON { (response) in
  switch response.result {
        case .Success:
            if let value = response.result.value {
                 print("JSON: \(value)") //**problem**
             }
        case .Failure(let error):
            print(error)
         }

}
```

**The server response format is :**

```
"result" : [
    {
      "rec_name" : "1.jpg",
      "data": {
                "base64": "/9j/4AAQSkZ",
                "__class__": "bytes"
              },
      "id" : 9,
      "name" : "1.jpg"
    },
    {
      "rec_name" : "2.jpg",
      "data": {
                "base64": "/9j/4AAQSkZ",
                "__class__": "bytes"
              },
      "id" : 10,
      "name" : "2.jpg"
    }
  ],
  "id" : 0
}
```

**But I am getting as follow: data(base64 String) is null**

```
"result" : [
    {
      "rec_name" : "1.jpg",
      "data" : null,
      "id" : 9,
      "name" : "1.jpg"
    },
    {
      "rec_name" : "2.jpg",
      "data" : null,
      "id" : 10,
      "name" : "2.jpg"
    }
  ],
  "id" : 0
}
```

Did I miss something for base64 string? 
I think it is working before a month but now I am getting issue.

**If I make same request via POSTMAN then it works fine!**

Thank you,

Comment: make sure that it is not your server side changes!! Because if it was working before as you said!

Comment: While posting request to server, check if it's successfully posted or not. If it's successfully posted then it is a server issue.

Comment: @Lion,I made same request via postman then it works fine!

Comment: @nirav How did you get this output? Probably you used wrong log format. Or how did you check that "data" is null?

Comment: @RomanPodymov, I am use `print(response.result.value)`

Comment: @nirav Add more code please. You don't need to show us what URL you are using, but we need to know how did you setup Alamofire manager and how did you parse result.

Comment: @nirav Or did you tried to check value of ["result"][0]["data"] with debugger?

Comment: @RomanPodymov, I did but it is the same.

Comment: @nirav Nevertheless add some code please, I cannot understand how did you received such data.

Comment: @RomanPodymov, please check now!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153658/discussion-between-roman-podymov-and-nirav).

Answer (score 1):

I can advice you library [SwiftyJSON](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON). This library allows you to parse JSON in Swift easily. Also, there is extension [AlamofireSwiftyJSON](https://github.com/Xinguang/AlamofireSwiftyJSON) that unites Alamofire and SwiftyJSON. Here is an example for your request:

```
if let urlToTest = URL.init(string: "your_URL") {

    Alamofire.request(urlToTest,
                      method: .get,
                      parameters: nil,
                      encoding: JSONEncoding.default,
                      headers: nil)
    .responseSwiftyJSON(completionHandler: { (response:DataResponse<JSON>) in

        let jsonResult = response.result
        if let jsonResultValue = jsonResult.value {

            if let resultArray = jsonResultValue["result"].array {

                if resultArray.count > 0 {

                    if let itemData = resultArray[0]["data"].dictionary {

                        if let itemDataBase64 = itemData["base64"]?.string {

                            print("Base 64 field value \(itemDataBase64)")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    })
}
```